# Controlling text length, without destroying center positioning

Tags: css, positioning

I have some body and page settings that are keeping everything nicely centered in my site, which is my objective.
However, I also have some text in the center, which currently is sprawled along the entire width of the page when it's long. Every time I try to set a css width property, like max width, it decides to go haywire with it's positioning, and land itself far left of the center.

I guess there's some issue with my overall page center positioning, and setting any type of width property to a div.

EX of things nicely centered, but sprawling text: https://www.flickr.com/photos/77598212@N03/34191523510/in/dateposted-public/

and when I try to set any sort of width:
https://www.flickr.com/photos/77598212@N03/34191523450/in/dateposted-public/

I'd appreciate any and all thoughts. Thank you. -Wilson
the css:

```
 *{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;

 }

body{
text-align:center; /*For IE6 Shenanigans*/
 }

button {
color: #900;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 150%;
text-transform: uppercase;


 }

h1{
margin-top:20px;
font-size: 250%;
overflow:hidden; /* older browsers */
font-family: hobeaux-rococeaux-sherman, sans-serif;



}

img {
max-width:500px;
max-height:340px;
box-shadow: 1px 5px 5px grey;
border-style: groove;
border-width: 1px;
margin-top:20px;
}

#ShowText{

overflow:hidden; /* older browsers */
word-wrap: break-word;
padding-top: 100px;

font-size: 18px;
font-family: vendetta, serif;
line-height: 25px;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a fixed width on a block element then simply give it `margin: 0 auto;` to center it.